# Combining an array within an array based on returned json objects angular 2

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I am having some trouble wrapping my head around this and hopefully i could get some help clearing things out. I have a json file that returns 3 objects which are put in an array. Within each object is also another json call to get more information for the object. I would like to return and merge the inner json call into the main object so each object's data is accessible from the object itself.

Here is the structure of my json file:

```
{
  "Animals": {
    "title": "Animals",
    "id": 1,
    "info": {
      "link": "urlLinkHere"
    }
  },
  "Cars": {
    "title": "Cars",
    "id": 2,
    "info": {
      "link": "urlLinkHere"
    }
  },
  "Food": {
    "title": "Food",
    "id": 3,
    "info": {
      "link": "urlLinkHere"
    }
  }
}
```

Each of the links returns a different set of data that is not similar to the other.

This is how my json will look after the inner get call has been made filling the objects into the main object - **UPDATED:**

```
{
  "Animals": {
    "title": "Animals",
    "id": 1,
    "info": {
      "link": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "gender": "Male",
          "dob": "2014-05-03T14:48:34-08:00",
          "location": "New York",
          "about": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "gender": "Male",
          "dob": "2014-05-03T14:48:34-08:00",
          "location": "North Carolina",
          "about": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
        },
        {
          "id": "3",
          "gender": "Female.",
          "dob": "2014-05-03T14:48:34-08:00",
          "location": "Texas",
          "about": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "Cars": {
    "title": "Cars",
    "id": 2,
    "info": {
      "link": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "make": "Ford",
          "price": "$15,000"
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "make": "BMW",
          "price": "$32,450"
        },
        {
          "id": "3",
          "make": "Aston Martin",
          "dob": "$203,231"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "Food": {
    "title": "Food",
    "id": 3,
    "info": {
      "link": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "uuid": "39ea8762-422b-11e7-a919-92ebcb67fe33",
          "name": "Ritz",
          "title": "Ritz",
          "fatPercent": 20
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "uuid": "39ea89ce-422b-11e7-a919-92ebcb67fe33",
          "name": "Cheetos",
          "title": "Cheetos",
          "fatPercent": 40
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "uuid": "39ea8ad2-422b-11e7-a919-92ebcb67fe33",
          "name": "Jello",
          "title": "Jello",
          "fatPercent": 32
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In my html this is what i tried. **UPDATED:**

```
<div *ngFor="let result of results: let i = index">
        <div class="header"> {{result.title}}</div>
        <div class="bodyContent" for-of="let item of subData; let i=index;">
            <div *ngIf="result.title == 'Animals'">
               {{item.gender}}, {{item.location}}
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="result.title == 'Cars'">
               {{item.make}}, {{item.price}}
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="result.title == 'Food'">
               {{item.name}}, {{item.fatPercentage}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is what i currently tried...

In my service file:

```
 getData(){
        return this._http.get('url')
        .map((res:Response) => res.json())
        .map((obj) => Object.keys(obj).map((key)=>{return obj[key]}))
        .catch(this.handleError);
    }
 getDataQuery(link:any){
        return this._http.get(link)
        .map((res:Response) => res.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

In my components file:

```
getData(){
    this.dataService.getData()
      .flatMap(data => {
        this.results = data;
        for(let x of this.results){
          var link = x.info.link;

          this.observables.push(this.dataService.getDataQuery(link));}

        return Observable.forkJoin(this.observables);}
      ).subscribe(data => {
        this.subData = data;
      });
```

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let result of results: let i = index">
    <div class="header"> {{result.title}}</div>
    <div class="bodyContent" *ngFor="let item of subData; let i=index;">
        Here i would like to have the returned data from the inner json call. 
    </div>
</div>
```

currently when i try debugging i can see the inner json file results for all the objects within the body - i would like it specified to the current item being displayed.

**EXAMPLE OF FETCHED DATA**

```
[
        {
          "id": "1",
          "gender": "Male",
          "dob": "2014-05-03T14:48:34-08:00",
          "location": "New York",
          "about": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "gender": "Male",
          "dob": "2014-05-03T14:48:34-08:00",
          "location": "North Carolina",
          "about": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
        },
        {
          "id": "3",
          "gender": "Female.",
          "dob": "2014-05-03T14:48:34-08:00",
          "location": "Texas",
          "about": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
        }
      ]
```

**Getting canvas dataset from forloop**

So i am trying to add a canvas using ng2-charts and the canvas requires a dataset and lables to draw out the x and y axis but i am having trouble populating x and y from a forloop

for example:

```
<div *ngSwitchCase="'Animals'">
      <div *ngFor="let item of result.details">
        <canvas [datasets]= "item.gender" [labels]="item.location" [chartType]="horizontalBar"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You are not getting an array? Seems the combined data is an object? Is that correct, it cannot be, if you can iterate it?

Comment: What is actually the content of `results`?

Comment: @AJT_82 so `results` contains the info for the outer object like `Animals, cars, food` but `subData` contains the returned json for each of call made within each animals, cars, food. Is there a way to return the subData so that it is an array and easy to iterate to display the data?

Comment: Okay, so they are not merged like the big object you are presenting?

Comment: I followed the answer given by Dummy below. Is there another way to get the data merged like how i have presented?

Comment: Well, okay you have the first JSON presented, good. Could you show how the second JSON looks like when you have fetched it. An example of one is enough. We'd need to know how it looks so we know how to merge them :)

Comment: @AJT_82 I updated my post and towards the bottom you will the the the fetched json BUT the fetched info is not the same for all info - each of the animals, cars, and food return a different data.

Comment: Yes I understand exactly what you mean, but just wanted a sample to work with (and test), an now I know the data comes as an array, even though the data and properties are different for all. I'll take a look and let you know! :)

Comment: @AJT_82 Thank you very much - really appreciate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is most likely a more elegant solution, I need to read up on my rxjs ;) But this is working:

Keep `getData` as is:

```ts
getData(){
    return this._http.get('url')
    .map((res:Response) => res.json())
    .map((obj) => Object.keys(obj).map((key)=>{return obj[key]}))
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Then your component subscribe:

```ts
ngOnInit() {
  this.dataService.getData()
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.results = data;
      // iterate array
      this.results.forEach(result => {
        // do second request based on the link
        this.dataService.getDataQuery(result.info.link)
          .subscribe(data => {
            // push result to object property 'details', or name of your choosing
            result.details = data
          })
      })
    })
}
```

and your `getDataQuery`:

```ts
 getDataQuery(link:any){
    return this._http.get(link)
      .map((res:Response) => res.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);
 }
```

Then you can use `[ngSwitch]` in your template:

```html
<div *ngFor="let result of results">
  <div class="header"><h3> {{result.title}}</h3></div>
  <div [ngSwitch]="result.title">
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'Animals'">
      <div *ngFor="let item of result.details">
        {{item.gender}}, {{item.location}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'Cars'">
      <!-- Properties here -->
    </div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'Food'">
      <!-- Properties here -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Finally a **[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/iKvPOQjivOMVCIxu1NxT?p=preview)** where for simplicity's sake the subsequent is returning same data, therefore I just hardcoded e.g 'Car data here'.

Comment: YES! FINALLY! I got it working thank you so very much! I will continue implementing all my parts  and if you don't mind could get back to you if i run into issues.

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked :) Sure, ping me if you have an issue and we'll see if I can help :)

Comment: I am trying to add in a bar graph and trying to populate the x and y axis from the `item` but it is not rendering in the canvas and wondered if you have an idea. I updated my post with the html of canvas (bottom of my post)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to overwrite the `link` property to contain an array after getting data by calling `getDataQuery`. Update the `getData` in your component like this

```
getData() {
  this.dataService.getData()
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.results = data;
      for (let x of this.results) {
        var link = x.info.link;
        this.dataService.getDataQuery(link)
                        .subscribe(data => {
                           // Assumes the data returned by getDataQuery function is an array
                           // If it is wrapped in a json object, just retrieve it
                           // like x.info.link = data.fieldName; for example
                           x.info.link = data;
                        });
      }
    });
}
```

Update your template like so

```
<div *ngFor="let result of results: let i = index">
    <div class="header"> {{result.title}}</div>
    <div class="bodyContent" *ngFor="let obj of result.info.link">
        <!-- to access the individual properties, just do obj.propertyName, etc -->
        {{ obj }} 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I will give this a try but i was wondering how will my html change?

Comment: so if i was adding the inner json to the main object wouldn't it be `x.info` because i don't have a `x.data` - unless if i am misunderstanding something.

Comment: you can add to the outer (main) object or to the `info` object under **any name** you want, I used `data` just to demonstrate the point, so if you want to add this *inner object* to *main object*'s `info` object, you do `mainObject.info.anyNameYouWant = data` in place of `x.data` there. Then in your template, you do `result.info.theNameThatYouUsed` to access this data

Comment: currently when i render my html i get this in my div: `[object, Object],[object,Object],[object,Object]` which is the correct number of objects for this div but when i try to put it in a *ngFor loop to show individual content within  i get this console error: `Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.`

Comment: it is because the data returned by `getDataQuery` is a json object, not an array so you can use `for-of` loop on it

Comment: i am still having trouble with displaying actual data instead of the `[object, Object]`- would you mind updating your answer with the `for-of`?

Comment: You need to update your post to show the structure of that inner object and what output you want to see

Comment: I have updated both my json and html towards the top of my original post - I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I am getting `Cannot read property 'stringify' of undefined` error in the console.

Comment: Looks like `JSON` is not visible inside a template, then just change `JSON.stringify(obj)` to `obj`

Comment: also tried that and the divs are empty. From your perspective how can the json be altered so that i get the display i want?

Comment: Like I said, you haven't posted how the data returned by `getDataQuery` looks like so, I have no idea how to help you